Host <chrome extension id> blocked
I'm writing an extension for chrome. I need to open a file on the path chrome-extension://id/folder/index.html, on my computer everything opens, but when I try to open it on my laptop it says host blocked.
(Extension unzipped)
How can I solve this problem?
P.S. I use manifest v3.
I tried to find something in the documentation and couldn't find it.
On all computers except my primary host is blocked

The id of an unpacked extension is different depending on its disk path, so instead of hardcoding it you should use chrome.runtime.getURL() or generate a "key" in manifest.json.

Thank you, i did redirect from my popup directly, but when i open from background with getURL it's work good

As wOxxOm said the extension should open by extension id, personally I used opening the tab via background.js


let url = chrome.runtime.getURL('page.html');
chrome.tabs.create({ url: url });



